# Exponential probability between two numbers?

Tags: c#, math

I would like to apologize if this question is vague, I can't quite think of the mathematical term to describe what I am trying to do.

I am developing a game where health powerups can have a random health value between a min and a max (5 - 100 as of now). I want to make it so higher health value powerups spawn less regularly.

How would I randomly generate a value between the min and max to follow an exponential model?

Comment: Its not easy. You may want to ask over on MathSE to get the equation/algorithm, then come here if you need help coding it.

Comment: Can you define the model? You say exponential. Can you define exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you were to plot x^1.75 on a graph thats what I would want the probability curve to look like.

Comment: Get a uniformly-distributed random float between 0 and 1 (I assume the standard random function is normal), then raise 100 to that. I believe (off the top of my head) that this is exactly an exponential distribution (though you might mean something different than I do by the term). This will give 1<x<=100, so might need adjusting.

Comment: you need an algorithm for transforming a uniform distribution into an exponential one.

Comment: Your curve gives higher values for higher x. So what is x, and what is the other axis, in your plot?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard For the record, the density corresponding to the method you specified is `p(x) = 1/(x log(100))`. That might or might not have the properties desired by OP, I don't know. But it is not an instance of an exponential distribution as the term is commonly used.

Comment: f(x) = a * Math.Exp(b * x).  Two variables, two specific results you want.  Solve a and b.  Use Math.Pow() is Exp goes too fast, tweak the 2nd argument.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yeah, you're totally right. I think the distribution is roughly along the lines of what OP was going for, but it's not exponential. Maybe logarithmic (having trouble doing the math in my head right now). In any case, I'll throw my vote to mybirthname's answer, since it gives a similarish curve, and is much easier to work with and adjust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not take random between 5 and 100 and after that multiple it with random between 1-10 divide by 10. In this case you will have in really rare cases high hp bar.

Example Random 5-100 takes 60, random 1-10 takes 5.

60*5/10=30.

Hope this works for you. In this case you will have hp over 90 with chance a little be over 1%.
If my math is correct for 80-90 is a ~4%, for 70-80 is ~9%.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int p = rnd.Next(5, 100);
        int q = rnd.Next(1, 10);

        int hp = p * q / 10;

        if (hp < 5)
            hp = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(hp);

    }
```

Comment: @ErenErsönmez If the value is under<5, take 5 ... You never written if statment. In this way if the value is not int, please convert it to int. Anyway thanks for the down vote !

Comment: I'm not saying you deserve a downvote, but it would be nice to see some proof that this works. There is already clearly one corner case, and there may be others. Its not a case of being able to write an if statement, its understanding the underlying math enough to make an accurate equation.

Comment: So far this seems to work well. I am seeing averages of ~28 out of 100 samples. Throwing the equation into wolfram alpha also shows a nice distribution. Thank you.

Comment: @ryansworld10 Some calculation shows that the density function for the method stated by mybirthname is: `log(min(b, x/c)/max(a, x/d))/((d - c)*(b - a))` where `x` is the product of the two uniform variables and the first variable is uniform on the range `(a, b)` and the second is uniform on the range `(c, d)`. As stated, `a = 1/10, b = 1, c = 5, d = 95`. Note that both very small (near `a*c`) and very large (near `b*d`) values of `x` are unlikely; dunno if that makes a difference in your game. You can pick different values of `a, b, c, d` and see what density you get and decide what you want.